# Number of solutions to multiplication equation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let *k* be a positive integer and let *m* be a non-negative integer. Find the number of solutions $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ to the equation $$x_1 x_2 ... x_k = 9^m$$ in positive integers $x_1,x_2,...,x_k$.

Comment: Each $x_i$ has to be a power of 3.

Comment: Related: find number of solutions in nonnegative integers to $y_1+y_2+\cdots+y_k=2m$.

Comment: I did a similar problem where $y_1...y_k$ were either 1 or 0, and the answer ended up being k choose n. But i cant for the life of me get this one started.

Comment: k choose m* sorry

Answer (score 0):

By @vadim123's representation, it is obvious that the problem is equivalent to the task of finding number of ways to distribute $2m$ equal units ("$1$"s) into $k$ ranges like this:

$$
\underbrace{|\underbrace{11...1}_{y_1}|\underbrace{11...1}_{y_2}|...|\underbrace{11...1}_{y_k}|}_k
$$

If we consider all $2m$ of "$1$"s and all $k-1$ of inner borders "|" (separating adjacent ranges) as permutating elements of a mixed sequence having length $2m+(k-1)$, then set of all such possible permutations will represent all possible distributions (including ranges with zero elements). Total number of permutations is $(2m+k-1)!$, however same permutations will repeat for $(2m)!$ different orderings of equal "$1$" elements and $(k-1)!$ different orderings of equal "|" elements, hence total number of distinct permutations is

$$
\frac{(2m+k-1)!}{(2m)!(k-1)!}=\binom{2m+k-1}{2m}
$$

which is the final answer for both OP's and @vadim123's representations of the problem.